# Restoring a model trained with tf.estimator and feeding input through feed_dict

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I trained a resnet with tf.estimator, the model was saved during the training process. The saved files consist of `.data`, `.index` and `.meta`. I'd like to load this model back and get predictions for new images. The data was fed to the model during training using `tf.data.Dataset`.  I have closely followed the resnet implementation given [here](https://github.com/deepaksuresh/models/blob/master/official/resnet/resnet.py).

I would like to restore the model and feed inputs to the nodes using a feed_dict.

**First attempt**

```
  #rebuild input pipeline
  images, labels = input_fn(data_dir, batch_size=32, num_epochs=1)

  #rebuild graph
  prediction= imagenet_model_fn(images,labels,{'batch_size':32,'data_format':'channels_first','resnet_size':18},mode = tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL).predictions 

  saver  = tf.train.Saver()
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(r'./model')
    saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
    while True:
    try:
        pred,im= sess.run([prediction,images])
        print(pred)
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
      break
```

I fed a dataset which was evaluated on the same model using `classifier.evaluate`, but the above method gives wrong predictions. The model gives same class and probability, 1.0, for all images.

**Second attempt**

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(r'.\resnet\model\model-3220.meta')
sess = tf.Session()
saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint(r'.\resnet\model'))
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
inputImage = graph.get_tensor_by_name('image:0')
logits= graph.get_tensor_by_name('logits:0')

#Get prediction
print(sess.run(logits,feed_dict={inputImage:newimage}))
```

This also gives wrong predictions compared to `classifier.evaluate`. I can even run `sess.run(logits)` without a `feed_dict`!

**Third attempt**

```
def serving_input_fn():
  receiver_tensor = {'feature': tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 384, 256, 3], dtype=tf.float32)}
  features = {'feature': receiver_tensor['images']}
return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, receiver_tensor)
```

It fails with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imagenet_main.py", line 213, in <module>
    tf.app.run(argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "C:\Users\Photogauge\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 124, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "imagenet_main.py", line 204, in main
    resnet.resnet_main(FLAGS, imagenet_model_fn, input_fn)
  File "C:\Users\Photogauge\Desktop\iprings_images\models-master\models-master\official\resnet\resnet.py", line 527, in resnet_main
    classifier.export_savedmodel(export_dir_base=r"C:\Users\Photogauge\Desktop\iprings_images\models-master\models-master\official\resnet\export", serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_fn)
  File "C:\Users\Photogauge\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 528, in export_savedmodel
    config=self.config)
  File "C:\Users\Photogauge\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 725, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "imagenet_main.py", line 200, in imagenet_model_fn
    loss_filter_fn=None)
  File "C:\Users\Photogauge\Desktop\iprings_images\models-master\models-master\official\resnet\resnet.py", line 433, in resnet_model_fn
    tf.argmax(labels, axis=1), predictions['classes'])
  File "C:\Users\Photogauge\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 316, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Photogauge\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py", line 208, in argmax
    return gen_math_ops.arg_max(input, axis, name=name, output_type=output_type)
  File "C:\Users\Photogauge\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py", line 508, in arg_max
    name=name)
  File "C:\Users\Photogauge\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 528, in _apply_op_helper
    (input_name, err))
ValueError: Tried to convert 'input' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported.
```

The code I used for training and building the model is as below:

Specification for parsing the dataset:

```
def parse_record(raw_record, is_training):
  keys_to_features = {
      'image/encoded':
          tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value=''),
      'image/class/label':
          tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.int64, default_value=-1),
  }
  parsed = tf.parse_single_example(raw_record, keys_to_features)
  image = tf.image.decode_image(
      tf.reshape(parsed['image/encoded'], shape=[]),3)
  image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32)
  label = tf.cast(
      tf.reshape(parsed['image/class/label'], shape=[]),
      dtype=tf.int32)
  return image, tf.one_hot(label,2)
```

The following function parses the data and creates batches for training

```
def input_fn(is_training, data_dir, batch_size, num_epochs=1):
  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
      filenames(is_training, data_dir))
  if is_training:
     dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=_FILE_SHUFFLE_BUFFER)
  dataset = dataset.flat_map(tf.data.TFRecordDataset)
  dataset = dataset.map(lambda value: parse_record(value, is_training),
                        num_parallel_calls=5)
  dataset = dataset.prefetch(batch_size)
  if is_training:
      dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=_SHUFFLE_BUFFER)
  dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs)
  dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

  iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
  images, labels = iterator.get_next()
  return images, labels
```

A classifier is created as below for training on train set and evaluation on validation set

```
classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
      model_fn=model_function, model_dir=flags.model_dir, config=run_config,
      params={
          'resnet_size': flags.resnet_size,
          'data_format': flags.data_format,
          'batch_size': flags.batch_size,
      })

    #Training cycle
     classifier.train(
         input_fn=lambda: input_function(
             training_phase=True, flags.data_dir, flags.batch_size, flags.epochs_per_eval),
         hooks=[logging_hook])
    # Evaluate the model 
    eval_results = classifier.evaluate(input_fn=lambda: input_function(
        training_phase=False, flags.data_dir, flags.batch_size))
```

This is how I tried to load and get predictions from the model.

What is the right way to restore a saved model and perform inference on it. I want to feed images directly without using `tf.data.Dataset`.

**Update**

1. The value of `ckpt` is after running `ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(r'./model')` is

   model_checkpoint_path: "./model\model.ckpt-5980"
   all_model_checkpoint_paths: "./model\model.ckpt-5060"
   all_model_checkpoint_paths: "./model\model.ckpt-5061"
   all_model_checkpoint_paths: "./model\model.ckpt-5520"
   all_model_checkpoint_paths: "./model\model.ckpt-5521"
   all_model_checkpoint_paths: "./model\model.ckpt-5980"
2. The output is same when I try `saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(r'.\resnet\model'))
3. Passing in full path to `saver.restore` gives the same output
   In all cases the same model, `model.ckpt-5980` was restored

Comment: About the first attempt: What is the value of `ckpt` after `ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(r'./model')`? What happens if you instead restore via `saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(r'.\resnet\model'))`? And what if instead you pass a string with the full path of the checkpoint instead to `restore`?

Comment: @GPhilo I've updated the question

Comment: Thanks. Since Tensorflow is not raining any errors during restoration and your update shows the checkpoint file you're loading should be the right one, my next guess is the data in the checkpoint itself.
I'm looking at your input pipeline for the training and I see no `shuffle`. Is your data shuffled somewhere?

Comment: Another interesting thing is, your checkpoint has a really low number. `5980` is the value of `global_step` when the checkpoint was saved, so -unless I'm missing something- your network saw a total of `32*5980 = 191360` samples.. that's hardly enough to train resnet. Are you *sure* the checkpoint actually contains weights of a trained network?

Comment: @GPhilo Yes, data is shuffled during training as `if is_training:
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=_FILE_SHUFFLE_BUFFER)`.
Inside the classifier, there is a method called `classifier.evaluate`, this usually takes the validation set as the input. I tried the test set on this method after the model was trained and saved, i.e. I commented out `classifier.train` and pointed the validation dataset directory to test directory. I could see that the same model, `model.ckpt-5980` was being restored and I got `84%` accuracy.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see that `shuffle`. The thing is, up there you're only shuffling the filenames, not the actual samples in the files. Unless you have one sample per tfrecord file (which I assume is not the case), all the samples in each file will be in the same order at every epoch.

Comment: @GPhilo Sorry, I missed out a line of code. There is one more shuffle after the records are parsed.

Comment: Here is detailed example with latest tensorflow version 1.7
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52222383/5904928

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: This answer will evolve as soon as more information comes available. I'm not sure this is the most appropriate way to do it, but it feels better than using just comments. Feel free to drop a comment to the answer if this is inapproriate.

#### About your second attempt:

I don't have much experience with the `import_meta_graph` method, but if `sess.run(logits)` runs without complaining, I think the meta graph contains also your input pipeline.

A quick test I just made confirms that the pipeline is indeed restored too when you load the metagraph. This means, you're not actually passing in anything via `feed_dict`, because the input is taken from the `Dataset`-based pipeline that was used when the checkpoint was taken. From my research, I can't find a way to provide a different input function to the graph.

#### About the first attempt:

You code looks right to me, so my suspicion is that the checkpoint file that gets loaded is somehow wrong. I asked some clarifications in a comment, I'll update this part as soon as that info is available

Comment: How did you test if the input pipeline is restored when metagraph is loaded?

Comment: I get the operations in the graph via `tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()` and I then inspect the list. The first items are Dataset-related operations

Answer (score 1):

If you have model pb or pb.txt then inference is easy. Using predictor module, we can do an inference. Check out [here](https://github.com/kishorenayar/Tensorflow-Solutions/blob/master/Problems-Solutions/text/finance-complaints/inference.py) for more information. For image data it will be something to similar to below example. Hope this helps !!

Example code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def extract_data(index=0, filepath='data/cifar-10-batches-bin/data_batch_5.bin'):
    bytestream = open(filepath, mode='rb')
    label_bytes_length = 1
    image_bytes_length = (32 ** 2) * 3
    record_bytes_length = label_bytes_length + image_bytes_length
    bytestream.seek(record_bytes_length * index, 0)
    label_bytes = bytestream.read(label_bytes_length)
    image_bytes = bytestream.read(image_bytes_length)
    label = np.frombuffer(label_bytes, dtype=np.uint8)  
    image = np.frombuffer(image_bytes, dtype=np.uint8)
    image = np.reshape(image, [3, 32, 32])
    image = np.transpose(image, [1, 2, 0])
    image = image.astype(np.float32)
   result = {
     'image': image,
     'label': label,
   }
   bytestream.close()
   return result


    predictor_fn = tf.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model(
  export_dir = saved_model_dir, signature_def_key='predictions')
    N = 1000
    labels = []
    images = []
    for i in range(N):
       result = extract_data(i)
       images.append(result['image'])
       labels.append(result['label'][0])
    output = predictor_fn(
      {
        'images': images,
      }
    )
```

Comment: I don't have a `.pb` or `.pbtxt` file. Like I mentioned in the question I have `.meta`. `.index`, and `.data` files, and also the checkpoint.
In order to use the `predictor` function, I have to export the model as `estimator.export_savedmodel(my_export_dir, serving_input_fn)`. It's the `serving_input_fn` I can't figure out

Comment: Here is an example how I would do. Let me know if it works for you.  
 https://gist.github.com/kishorenayar/b9991b673b06b449703c07e3626982e5

Comment: Thanks Kishore. I've updated my question. Please take a look the the section "Third attempt".

Comment: I have opened another question related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48726633/piping-the-output-of-dataset-iterator-through-a-placeholder)

Comment: @dpk, Are you using tf-record as a input dataset to the estimator model ?

Comment: The dataset is stored as a `tfrecord` file. The input pipeline is built with `tf.data.Dataset`

Comment: Please find it [here](https://github.com/deepaksuresh/models/blob/master/official/resnet/resnet.py)